# Ajax form is sent twice if validation errors take place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know about `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. But it doesn't work for me. In my case I have such ajax call:

```
$('#templateConfirmDialog').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $(this).find('.modal-yes').click(function(){
                var form = form2js('search_form', '.', true, function (node) {}, false);
                var requestData = JSON.stringify(form, replacer);
                var $formErrors = $('.search_form').find('.alert-danger');
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    url: '/fraud/template/testCreate',
                    data: requestData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:  function (data) {
                        $formErrors.text('');

                         //if no errors just reload
                        if (data === undefined || data.length === 0) {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        else {

                            //else bind error messages
                            data.forEach(function(error) {
                                $('#new-' + error.field + '-error').text(error.defaultMessage);
                            })
                        }
                    }
                });
});
```

My problem is that the ajax call is prevented as much times as I made attempts to input data. If I entered invalid data once - ajax is called twice. If twice - 3 times. What may be a reason of such behavior?

Comment: How do you define "not valid data"?  What mechanism here prevents the AJAX call if data isn't valid?  There's nothing here which is submitting the AJAX call twice.  Are you *clicking the button* twice?  Once to submit the invalid data and once to submit the valid data?  Or perhaps the `'show.bs.modal'` event is happening more than once, and thus you're binding multiple click events?

Comment: maybe the reason is that all this is happen inside document.ready()? how to unbind click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time this event happens:

```
$('#templateConfirmDialog').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
```

You bind a new click event handler:

```
$(this).find('.modal-yes').click(function(){
```

So if you `show.bs.modal` twice, then you have two `click` event handlers both submitting the AJAX request.  Instead, just bind the `click` event handler *once* to the target clickable element, instead of binding it every time the modal is displayed.

Replace this:

```
$('#templateConfirmDialog').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $(this).find('.modal-yes').click(function(){
        //...
    });
});
```

With this:

```
$('#templateConfirmDialog').find('.modal-yes').click(function(){
    //...
});
```

Or, if that element is dynamically added to the DOM, this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#templateConfirmDialog .modal-yes', function(){
    //...
});
```

That way there's just a single click event handler created when the page loads, rather than adding a new handler every time you display the modal.

Comment: oh my fail. Thank you very much :)